# Permutations on circular table so that i cannot go to i or i+1.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, problem-solving, recursion, combinatorial-proofs

Suppose $n$ objects are placed in a circular table in clockwise order. Find the no of permutations where $i$ cannot go to $i$ or $i+1$. i.e. $1$ cannot be mapped to $1$ or $2$, $2$ cannot be mapped to $2$ or $3$,... , $n$ cannot be mapped to $n$ or $1$.

Say the required no is $T(n)$.

What I did, first I fix $1 \in \{1,2,..,n\}.$ Now, $1$ can go to some $k \in \{3,4,..,n\}$ in $\binom{n-2}{1} = n-2$ ways.

Case 1. If $k\neq n$, then two subcases appear.

SubCase 1. $k \to 1$ and $1 \to k$. Rest can be arranged in $T(n-2)$ ways.

SubCase 2. $k \to$ some other element and from some other element comes back to $1$. We can consider 1 and k as same unit and can consider arrangement in $n-1$ elements in $T(n-1)$ ways.

Total count for case 1 is $(n-2)*\{T(n-2)+T(n-1)\}$.

Case 2. If $k = n$. This is the case where I stucked. Now how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_problem

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown in this example, the partners are unique. i.e. wife's husband is you only. hence, cycles are of length 2. but in the problem, the cycles could be of any size. I'm not getting enough similarity to crack from where I am  left out. btw, in menage problem, 1 cannot move to n, nut in out problem exactly where I'm getting an issue.

Comment: I computed the counts:
$$0,0,1,2,13,80,579,4738,43387$$
which leads to the oeis sequence: https://oeis.org/A000179

Comment: What does "mapped" mean? Circular permutations are *not* maps (unlike regular permutations).

Comment: i cannot be mapped to i or i+1 means i can go to anywhere but i or i+1

Comment: "Go to anywhere"? What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

you may should try come to the problem from another angle: take the amount of all the permutations in a circle, which is $(n-1)!$, and decrease all the problematic permutations (every one's which mapping at least one element to itself) by using the "inclusion-exclusion principle".

for more info look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle